# Find and later delete zombie informatica objects

Tags: informatica

Is there a easy way to identify and clean unused informatica artifacts?

Context: In one of the projects, there are lot of zombie sessions / mappings etc, the creators have long gone.

**I want to do the following:**

1. List/Delete all sessions that are not associated with a workflow.
2. List/Delete all mappings that are not used in any session/wf.
3. List/Delete all source/target that were not used in any mapping.
4. List/Delete all workflows that were not run in the past one year.

Someone mentioned about using : Designer > Tools > Queries . I can't express the above 1/2/3/4 with the option given, can anyone shed some light?

**Note:**

- I’m not looking for click one by one and find dependencies.
- I’m not looking for download the whole plant as xml and search dependencies
  one by one

Comment: Hi! Queries are indeed not too useful. I'm working on some solution. Can you please let me know if you still need it? I hope to have it ready by the end of the week. I will need your support on testing it. Please let me know.

Comment: That would be great. Let me know when I can test your script. If it is not too-much to ask, are the scripts linux compatible?

Comment: It's ready. Please see the answer below. The scripts use Windows PowerCenter client pmrep tool. It would be possible to create linux version but I don't have an environment at hand. Perhaps some day ;)

Comment: Hi Maciejg, can you paste/attach the scripts as plain txt file in here? zip file download is restricted due to security issues.

Comment: This will not be that simple. My solution is a simple Python script but it's using few different modules complied. In this case you'd need to create a shell script. In general the idea is to call "pmrep listobjects" for all object types and then "pmrep listobjectdependencies" for each object. If the latter returns only 1 object (self), than it can be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is not easily achievable with PowerCenter itself, I tried to come up with some simple tool to solve it. For the full description and download link please go to [this page](http://powercenternotes.blogspot.com/2014/05/repository-cleanup.html).

Below you'll find the code published as requested in comments: [Find and later delete zombie informatica objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23254243/find-and-later-delete-zombie-informatica-objects)

Feel free to use, share and improve :) Any code review will be also much appreciated.

```
import subprocess
import os
from subprocess import *
import platform
import sys
import getpass
import configparser


#global variables declarations
currentDir=''
pmrepPath=''
domainFile=''


def connect_to_repo(Repository,Domain,User,Host,Port, UserSecurityDomain):
        #password = raw_input("Enter password for Repository: " + Repository + ", User: " + User)
        password = getpass.getpass()
        print "\nConnecting..."
        if Domain != '':
            RepoCommand="pmrep connect -r "+Repository+" -d "+Domain+" -n "+User + " -x " + password #+" -X DOMAIN_PWD"
        else:
            RepoCommand="pmrep connect -r "+Repository+" -n "+User + " -x " + password + " -h " + Host + " -o " + Port
        if UserSecurityDomain != '':
            RepoCommand += " -s " + UserSecurityDomain
        RepoCommand=RepoCommand.rstrip()
        p=subprocess.Popen(RepoCommand,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
        out,err=p.communicate()
        if p.returncode or err:
                print "Connection Failed"
                print err.strip()
                print out.strip()
                sys.stdout.flush()
                sys.stdin.flush()
        else:
                print "Connection Successful"
                sys.stdout.flush()
                sys.stdin.flush()
        return p.returncode

def execute_pmrep_command(command, output_file_name, start_line, end_line, line_prefix):
        if len(line_prefix)>0: line_prefix+=' '
        out=open(output_file_name,'a')
        return_code=subprocess.Popen(command,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
        output,error=return_code.communicate()
        for line in output.split('\r\n')[start_line:end_line]:
            out.writelines(line_prefix + line + '\n')

        out.close()
        return

def check_platform():
        global domainFile
        global currentDir
        global pmrepPath
        global platForm
        platForm=platform.system()
        print "Platform recognized : "+platForm
##        if not os.getenv('INFA_HOME', 'C:\\Informatica\\9.5.1'):
##                print "INFA_HOME env_variable not set in your "+platForm+" platform."
##                print "Please set INFA_HOME and continue."
##                raw_input()
##                sys.exit(0)
        if not os.getenv('INFA_DOMAINS_FILE'):
                print "INFA_DOMAINS_FILE env_variable not set in your "+platForm+" platform."
                print "Please set INFA_DOMAINS_FILE and continue."
                raw_input()
                sys.exit(0)
##        elif not os.getenv('DOMAIN_PWD', 'vic'):
##                print "DOMAIN_PWD env variable not set in your "+platForm+" platform."
##                print "Please set DOMAIN_PWD and continue."
##                raw_input()
##                sys.exit(0)

##        else:
##                if platForm == 'Windows':
##                        pmrepPath=os.getenv('INFA_HOME').strip()+"\clients\PowerCenterClient\client\\bin"
##                elif platForm == 'Linux':
##                        pmrepPath=os.getenv('INFA_HOME').strip()+"/server/bin"
##                currentDir=os.getcwd()
##                domainFile=os.getenv('INFA_DOMAINS_FILE','C:\\Informatica\\9.5.1\\domains.infa').strip()


config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
config.optionxform = lambda option: option
config.read('InfaRepo_ListUnusedObjects.cfg')

infaDir = config.get('Common', 'infaDir').strip()
Repository = config.get('Common', 'Repository').strip()
Domain = config.get('Common', 'Domain').strip()
Host = config.get('Common', 'Host').strip()
Port = config.get('Common', 'Port').strip()
Folder = config.get('Common', 'Folder').strip()
User = config.get('Common', 'User').strip()
UserSecurityDomain = config.get('Common', 'UserSecurityDomain').strip()
objectTypeList = config.get('Common', 'objectTypeList').split(',')

if Domain != '':
    print 'Domain provided, will be used to connect.'
else:
    print 'Domain not provided, Host and Port will be used to connect.'

for i in range(len(objectTypeList)):
    objectTypeList[i]=objectTypeList[i].strip()

currentDir=os.getcwd()
outputDir=currentDir+'\\UnusedObjectsReport'

###objectTypeList = ['mapplet', 'mapping', 'session', 'source', 'target', 'worklet']
##
##objectTypeList = ['target']

pmrepPath=infaDir.strip()+"\clients\PowerCenterClient\client\\bin"

os.chdir(pmrepPath)

outFile = outputDir + "\ListOfUnusedObjects.txt"
if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(outFile)):
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(outFile))
print 'Output file: ' + outFile
open(outFile,'w').writelines("Domain :  "+Domain+"\nRepository : "+Repository+"\nUserName : "+User+"\n")
open(outFile,'a').writelines("***************************"+"\n")
open(outFile,'a').writelines("LIST OF UNUSED OBJECTS:\n")

outBatchFile = outputDir + "\DeleteUnusedObjects.bat"
tempDir = outputDir + "\\temp"
if not os.path.exists(outputDir):
        os.makedirs(outputDir)
if not os.path.exists(tempDir):
        os.makedirs(tempDir)

for tempFile in os.listdir(tempDir):
    os.remove(os.path.join(tempDir, tempFile))

print 'Output batch file: ' + outBatchFile

if Domain != '':
    RepoCommand="pmrep connect -r "+Repository+" -d "+Domain+" -n "+User
else:
    RepoCommand="pmrep connect -r "+Repository+" -n "+User + " -h " + Host + " -o " + Port
if UserSecurityDomain != '':
    RepoCommand += " -s " + UserSecurityDomain

open(outBatchFile,'w').writelines(pmrepPath+"\\"+RepoCommand+"\n")

objectTypeCounter=0

return_code=connect_to_repo(Repository,Domain,User,Host,Port,UserSecurityDomain)

objDepDict={}

error = False
errorList = []

#check if repository connection is successfull
if return_code==0:
    for objectType in objectTypeList:
        objectTypeCounter+=1
        print "Step {0} of {1}: {2}".format(objectTypeCounter, len(objectTypeList), objectType)

        objectFile = tempDir + "\\" + objectType + ".txt"
        open(objectFile,'w').writelines("")

        objectDepFile = tempDir + "\\" + objectType + "_dep.txt"
        open(objectDepFile,'w').writelines("")
        execute_pmrep_command("pmrep listobjects -f " + Folder + " -o " + objectType, objectFile, 8, -4, '')

        objectList=open(objectFile).readlines()

        objectCounter=0

        if len(objectList) == 0:
            print '\tNo {0}s found'.format(objectType)

        elif objectList[0][:3] == ' [[':
            error=True
            for line in objectList:
                errorList += [line.replace('\n','')]
            break


        for line in objectList:
                objectCounter+=1
                fields=line.split(' ')
                if len(fields) == 2:
                    objectType=fields[0]
                    objectName=fields[1][:-1]
                else:
                    objectType=fields[0]
                    objectName=fields[2][:-1]
                    #if the object is non-reusable, it obviously is in some workflow, so skipp it
                    if fields[1] == 'non-reusable':
                        print "\t{0} {1} of {2}: {3} is not a reusable {4} - skipping".format(objectType, objectCounter, len(objectList), objectName, objectType)
                        continue

                command = "pmrep listobjectdependencies -f " + Folder + " -n " + objectName + " -o " + objectType + " -p parents"
                #print "Getting object dependencies for " + objectType + " " + objectName

                print "\t{0} {1} of {2}: {3}".format(objectType, objectCounter, len(objectList), objectName)

                execute_pmrep_command(command, objectDepFile, 8, -6, objectName)

        #find unused objects

        for fileLine in open(objectDepFile,'r').readlines():
            line = fileLine.split(' ')
            if len(line) == 3:
                Name = line[0]
                ParentType = line[1]
                ParentName = line[2]
            else:
                Name = line[0]
                ParentType = line[1]
                ParentName = line[3]
            try:
                objDepDict[objectType + ': ' + Name]+=[ParentType + ' ' + ParentName]
            except:
                objDepDict[objectType + ': ' + Name]=[ParentType + ' ' + ParentName]


    found = False
    for objectKey in objDepDict.iterkeys():
        objectType, objName = objectKey.replace(' ','').split(':')
        if len(objDepDict[objectKey]) <= 1:
            if not found:
                print '\n'
                print 'Following unused objects have been found:'
                found = True
            print '\t{0}: {1}'.format(objectType, objName)
            open(outFile,'a').writelines('{0}: {1}\n'.format(objectType, objName))
            open(outBatchFile,'a').writelines("rem {0}\\pmrep deleteobject -f {1} -o {2} -n {3}\n".format(pmrepPath, Folder, objectType, objName))

    execute_pmrep_command('pmrep cleanup', 'log.txt', 0, 0, '')

    open(outBatchFile,'a').writelines(pmrepPath+'\\pmrep cleanup' + '\n')

    if not error:
        if not found:
            print 'No unused objects found.'
        print '\nDone.'
        print 'Output file: ' + outFile
        print 'Output batch file: ' + outBatchFile
    else:
        print 'Following errors occured:'
        for e in errorList:
            print '\t', e
#wait for key press
print '\nHit Enter to quit...'
raw_input()
#End of program
```

Comment: It is useful if your answer/script is in this same page. I went to your page and checked, there is no script or zip file (it was there few months back). Can you please add the script code here for everyone to view?

Comment: The zip flie is back - sorry for inconvenience. I don't feel like publishing the code however. It's working fine but would require quite some rework and refactoring before I'd dare to show it to the world.

Comment: This forum has a spirit of "openness" "improve" "collaborate". In that spirit it is better to put the code out. Unless you have monitizing intention masked as 'rework'. Others will help improve the code, make it generic etc.

Comment: Hi Maciejg, Will try testing the code, though I've moved to a different project.